# Android Studio 4.0.1, Gradle, and React Native: AndroidManifest.XML not found when it exists

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

**INTRO**

Greetings, all!

My Android Studio 4.0.1 project refused to build due to not being able to find an AndroidManifest.xml file that's in /main/ where it should be, according to the documentation.  Mass replacing the occurrences of "api" with "implementation" or vice versa hasn't helped.

Thus, what other information do you want for clarification, and what should change to ensure this works?

Thankee!

**MANIFEST FILE**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.hornet">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**RUN ERRORS WITH DEBUG MODE ACTIVE**

Moved to this Google Doc for being too long for this post!

https://docs.google.com/document/d/19OO-OIzFy6IXPEOAdvGZLgXNsW_1sfiZsLDs6H0Jjzs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Adding the exact error stack always helps.

Comment: @francisduvivier
Build and run errors added at your request!  Enjoy and thankee!

Comment: Thanks, but have no real clue on this. Hopefully someone else can figure something out from the error stack. But they could be improved. 1. Not the full stack is shown, 2. Would be better to work with Gradle from the command line and add the --debug flag to the command and then post the result of that

Comment: @francisduvivier
Debug feedback added at your request.  Enjoy and thankee!

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild the project or modify project structure. It happens when something was wrong

Comment: Greetings!

I've manually ordered the code cleaned and rebuilt in Android Studio and I get the same error messages.  What else do you suggest?

Thankee!

@Daniele Romanella